# ClassNotFoundException in ad.loadClass in Android 9 (API 28)

Tags: android, admob

I have an app in the production, and some of the users in Android 9 are getting this error:

```
 ClassNotFoundException in ad.loadClass in Android 9 (API 28)
```

Here is more detailed report, it seems that something wrong with ads. 
I'm using this version of google ads:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1'
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I added to Manifest, this line, and it seems that this error disappeared:

```
 <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />
```